# Displaying Iframe Values

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to display angle of a dial. I have four dials. I got my code working for one dial. I would appreciate your suggestion on how can i display all my dial value. Here is my code.

```
function myAngle() {
    var angleVal = window.frames['clkwise1'].document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
    var angleVal1 = window.frames['antiClkwise1'].document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
    var angleVal2= window.frames['clkwise2'].document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
    var angleVal3= window.frames['antiClkwise2'].document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
    var angleVal4 = window.frames['clkwise3'].document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;


    document.getElementById("anglesvalue").innerHTML = angleVal, angleVal1;
```

// And here is how I pull out the Value on-click. It works fine for first angle value

```
<p <b id="anglesvalue"></b></p>
<input  type= button id= bttn name= bttn onclick= "myAngle()"  value= "Get Angle" />
```

Comment: Your question is not quite clear.

Comment: I need to display the angleval, angleval1,angleval2... on-click. I have five iframes. Is there a way I can show all of the values in a single line..Does it make sense? Thank you

Comment: why dont just concat them then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just concat them into one string: Q_Q

```
document.getElementById("anglesvalue").innerHTML = angleVal+ angleVal +  angleVal2 + angleVal3 + angleVal4;
```

EDIT: if you want to separate by coma do the following:

```
document.getElementById("anglesvalue").innerHTML = angleVal+', '+ angleVal1 +', '+  angleVal2 +', '+ angleVal3 +', '+ angleVal4;
```

Comment: That would add up the values..I want all the values to be displayed seperated by comma..

Comment: Use: angleVal+", " + angleVal2 ...etc